# Clicking on a button with changing xpath

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I just started working with Selenium webdriver to try automate clicking a button in a discord chat based on preconditions. The problem I am having is being able to classify this button.

For starters, the HTML code is as follows:

```
<div tabindex="0" class="reactionInner-15NvIl" aria-label="♥️, press to react" aria-pressed="false" role="button"><img src="/assets/1afd3c799f3e158662a70498e83e2a87.svg" alt="♥️" draggable="false" class="emoji"><div class="reactionCount-2mvXRV" style="min-width: 9px;">1</div></div>
```

What I first tried to do was to find_element_by_xpath:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div[48]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div').click()
```

But, when a new opportunity for this reaction comes up, the xpath changes:

```
/html/body/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div[50]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div
```

Notice the only part changing it the div[48] to div[50]

The next thing I tried was to find_element_by_class_name:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_class_name('reactionInner-15NvIl')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
```

The reason I did this was because I was having a problem with simply doing:

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name('reactionInner-15NvIl').click()
```

That code would give me an error saying `Message: element click intercepted: Element <div tabindex="0" class="reactionInner-15NvIl" aria-label=", press to react" aria-pressed="false" role="button">...</div> is not clickable at point (405, 94). Other element would receive the click: <span id="NewMessagesBarJumpToNewMessages_122" class="span-3ncFWM">...</span>` and the code wouldn't run. The program runs with the execute_script but it just isn't doing anything, the button is not being clicked. So if anyone has any idea how to be able to click this button, any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can use xpath in a better way than navigate between the divs, like you did the first time.

First of all, if you can change the HTML to use `id`, or `name`, thats better.

In this case, you could use this xpath:

`//div[@class = "reactionInner-15NvIl"]`

When searching by class, this could return multiple results, so use the function `find_elements_by_xpath`, and then choose the exactly one

Answer (score 0):

Induce `WebDriverWait` and wait for `element_to_be_clickable()` and following css selector.

```
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div[class*='reactionInner-'][role='button']"))).click()
```

You need to import following libraries.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

---

**Update**:

Induce `Javascript Executor` to click.

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div[class*='reactionInner-'][role='button']"))))
```

Comment: Im getting the same error. 
Message: element click intercepted: Element <div tabindex="0" class="reactionInner-15NvIl" aria-label=", press to react" aria-pressed="false" role="button">...</div> is not clickable at point (405, 94). Other element would receive the click: <span id="NewMessagesBarJumpToNewMessages_122" class="span-3ncFWM">...</span>

Comment: @DannyGonzalez : Check my updated answer and let me know how this goes.

Comment: nothing happens, i dont get an error now but its not doing anything